# Access GitHub repository through proxy

Tags: python, github, pygithub

I am trying to get repositories from my Github ut I get following error:

```
  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tejasshah2227/user/repos (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024E647925F8>, 'Connection to github.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)'))
```

I guess I am getting this error because I am accessing this through a proxy. But I can't find anything that will help me fix this issu.

Following is my code:

```
from github import Github

g = Github("userID", "password")
print(g.get_user())

for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
      print(repo.name)
```

Also, when I printed this:

```
 print(g.get_user())
```

I get following as the output:

```
AuthenticatedUser(login=None)
```

Can anyoe help me with this?

Comment: have you tried using git from the command line? does it work?

Comment: Yes. the command line works perfectly fine!